# Finite or polynomial number integral points clarification on Coppersmith's theorems (possibility of ellipse counter example?)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, computational-number-theory

Coppersmith states if $f(x,y)$ is an irreducible bivariate with total degree $\delta$ then if he can list all roots $(X,Y)$ of the polynomial in $\mathsf{poly}(\log D,\delta)$ time if the roots satisfy $(XY)^{\delta}\leq\frac{D}{2^{O(\delta^2)}}$ where $D=\max_{i,j}|f_{i,j}X^iY^j|$ (https://dominoweb.draco.res.ibm.com/8393c7441feac76985256593006f9094.html)

> Does he implicitly assume the polynomial has only polynomially many integral roots?

If the polynomial has super polynomial number of integral roots within the bound the theorem cannot be true and although I do not know of a polynomial satisfying his bounds and has superpolynomial in $\log D$ number of integral roots it is possible there are quadratic examples (a quadratic with superpolynomial number of roots is $xy-N=0$ when $N$ is square-free and has maximum possible number of prime factors but the roots do not satisfy the bounds).

---

I am looking for a reference which states either

1. Coppersmith type theorem's will only apply to bivariates with finite number of integral points

or 2. if Coppersmith type bounds apply to a bivariate quadratic (hence genus $0$) then the number of integral roots within the bound for the polynomial is necessarily at most polynomial in number.

---

Is there an equation family of ellipses

$$a^2x^2\pm xy+c^2y^2+dx+ey+f=0$$
such that the number of integral points which satisfy

$$(XY)^2\leq\frac D{2^{26}}$$
where $D=\max(|a^2X^2|,|XY|,|c^2Y^2|,|dX|,|eY|,|f|)$

grows as a function of $\exp\Big(\frac{\log(D)}{(\log\log(D))^2}\Big)$?

Since $xy$ coefficient has absolute value $1$ and $x^2$,$y^2$ coefficients are squares it is an ellipse while keeping the polynomial irreducible.

I think there should be an infinite family of counterexamples (which implies infinite family of curves which respect Coppersmith's bounds yet possess superpolynomial number of bounded integer roots which would stipulate Coppersmith style theorems necessitate apripri knowledge of polynomial number of integral points  satisfying the needed bounds for theorems to apply).

Comment: I think you are looking for Siegel's theorem: if a genus 0 curve has at least three places at infinity, then it has only finitely many integral points. For example, consider the genus 0 curve defined by $x + y = 1, xz = 1, yt = 1$ defined over $\mathbb{R}^4$ say. This curve has genus 0 and three places at infinity (i.e., equivalent to $\mathbb{P}^3 \setminus \{0,1,\infty\}$) so only has finitely many integral points. In general, we do not know how to obtain a good upper bound for the size or number of the integral points.

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao the polynomials I am concerned are just bivariate and are of form $f(x,y)-m=0$ where $f$ is degree $2$ homogeneous and the polynomial $f(x,y)-m$ is irreducible. The desired roots are of size $T^a$ where $T$ is largest coefficient magnitude and $a$ in $(0,1)$ respects Coppersmith's bounds with regards to $T$ and degree $2$. Is there something that would prevent such roots to be arbitrarily many as $T$ increases? This is the finer problem. I do not think Siegel's theorem is relevant.

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao Please Refer theorem 4 and 5 in https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-24676-3_29 for the bounds. The coefficients sizes are large compared to desired roots sizes and that is the only extraneous factor outside genus $0$ degree $2$ irreducibility nature.

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao any further suggestions?

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao If you had a reasonable answer please address and I can award the bounty to you instead of wasting.

Comment: Have you tried writing to Coppersmith?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I do not know his email address.

Comment: Neither do I. But I bet that if you wanted to contact him, you'd be able to find a way to do it.

Comment: I am a small fry.

Comment: People are generally pleased when someone – anyone – expresses an interest in their work.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I tried asking several professors but there was no response. And Coppersmith does not seem to have recent publications and so it is hard to get hold of his recent email.

Answer (score 1):

My personal opinion is since the final steps of Coppersmith's algorithm is based on elimination theory it is impossible the algorithm handles the scenarios of arbitrary number of integral points on degree $2$ curves without somehow increasing the degree of the final polynomial. I believe Coppersmith assumes he handles the scenarios involving $RSA$ semiprimes where number of roots is apriori fixed and so the theorems should be taken in cryptographic context.