# Polynomial sized arithmetic map from circle to ellipse preserving integral points

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, computer-science

Let $n$ be a square free integer and a product of $O(m/\log m)$ number of primes $1\bmod 4$ where $m$ is $\log_2n$.

Take the circle around origin of radius $n^2$. It has ${\exp}(m/\log m)$ number of integral points on the boundary by standard results in quadratic forms.

Is there an 'operator' describable by a $\mathsf{poly}(m)$ sized circuit to map the circle to an ellipse (perhaps not around origin) given by

$$a_{2,0}x^2+a_{1,1}xy+a_{0,2}y^2+a_{1,0}x+a_{0,1}y+a_{0,0}=0$$

which preserves every integral point on the circle (total count is exactly identical) and which can compute the point on the circle given a point on the ellipse and  satisfy $$n^4\leq\max_{i,j}\big|a_{i,j}X^iY^j\big|$$ holds for every integral point on the ellipse keeping the bivariate itself irreducible (it provides counterexample requested in [Finite or polynomial number integral points clarification on Coppersmith's theorems (possibility of ellipse counter example?)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/378315/finite-or-polynomial-number-integral-points-clarification-on-coppersmiths-theor))?

Comment: The complexity of the map is important or we can pick an ellipse (possibly constructible in polynomial time) containing similar number of integral points and assign an arbitrary bijection.